# Annotation function with filter causing too generic error

Tags: generics, elm

I am trying to create a generic function to be able to accept a `Maybe List` of any record with an `id : Int` as a field, to find if an `id` exists in that list. The return could be one of three states, the `Found record`, `NotFound`, and a `Loading` message (for when the list is `Nothing`).

The errors have led me to this code so far, but am now stuck and don't understand how to fix this from the the error help (including reading through [the link](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/0.17.0/hints/type-annotations.md)). How can I get this to work, and why exactly does this not work?

```
import Html exposing (text)

type alias RecordWithID a =
  { a | id : Int }


type alias MyRecord =
  { id : Int
  , name : String
}

type Find a
  = Found (RecordWithID a)
  | NotFound
  | Loading


findById : Int -> Maybe (List (RecordWithID a)) -> Find (RecordWithID a)
findById id maybeItems =
  case maybeItems of
    Just items ->
      let
        head = List.head <| List.filter (\x -> x.id == id) items
      in
        case head of
          Just item ->
            Found item

          Nothing ->
            NotFound

    Nothing ->
      Loading


main = text <| toString <| findById 4 (Just [ MyRecord 4 "hi" ])
```

## Edit

The error:

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------------------------

The type annotation for `findById` does not match its definition.

17| findById : Int -> Maybe (List (RecordWithID a)) -> Find (RecordWithID a)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The type annotation is saying:

    Int -> Maybe (List { b | id : Int }) -> Find { b | id : Int }

But I am inferring that the definition has this type:

    Int -> Maybe (List { b | id : Int }) -> Find b

Hint: A type annotation is too generic. You can probably just switch to the type
I inferred. These issues can be subtle though, so read more about it.
<https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/0.17.0/hints/type-annotations.md>
```

I understand that the type of the record from the filter and head won't necessarily match `a`, but unsure on how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will compile successfully if you redefine `Find a` more generically:

```elm
type Find a
  = Found a
  | NotFound
  | Loading
```

Or, if you kept the definition of `Find a` as you originally coded it, you could annotate your function like this:

```elm
findById : Int -> Maybe (List (RecordWithID a)) -> Find a
```

Why does it work this way? I can only speculate. It *feels* a little like a typeclass constraint in Haskell (e.g. `findById :: Record a => Int -> Maybe (List a) -> Find a`, since `a` in the Elm version is only allowed to be constrained in the annotation once. I don't know whether this is true when it comes to the compiler but that's what it feels like. Again, that's just speculation.